# when we write void variable like void *p ; cout<<&p; cout<<p; so it give two different address but why?

Tags: c++, void-pointers

**C++** output give two different address
but why complier give two address instead of I am writing only one variable

```
void *p ;
cout<<&p<<p;
```

Comment: Between the two lines, put in `p = &p;` and Bob's your uncle.

Comment: It's essentially the same as `int i; std::cout << &i << i;`. An object and its address are two different things, regardless of the type of the object.

Answer (score 1):

`p` is a pointer and it points to a different place in memory, which you can access with `*p`. 
However the pointer itself is stored somewhere, so `&p` returns the address of the pointer itself.

Answer (score 0):

`void *p ;` is an uninitialized pointer. So what you will have inside the pointer there is actual garbage. When you do `&p`, your returning the address of the pointer `p`. That's why they both return different values.

Comment: undefined behavior != garbage

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 What I mean by "garbage" is the actual data stored in it as the OP is not assigning anything to it.

Comment: You means to say that initialized pointer store the garbage address like initialized variable store the garbage value ? is I am right

Comment: @HT3163 Not necessarily. When a variable is uninitialized, it can contain unwanted values. Its when you initialize the variable that you get the desired values. Its not strict though.